# Why does javac emit "error: method in class cannot be applied to given types" when an instance method is used in a static context?

Tags: java, java-8, javac

Consider the following (invalid) Java program:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ints = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        print(ints);
    }

    public void print(int... ints) {
        for (int i : ints) { 
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect an error similar to this:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method print(int[]) from the type Test
at Test.main(Test.java:5)
```

but instead, javac emits:

```
Test.java:5: error: method print in class Test cannot be applied to given types;
    print(ints);
    ^
required: int[]
found: int[]
reason: varargs mismatch; int[] cannot be converted to int
1 error
```

javac -version `javac 1.8.0_11`
java -version

```
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)
```

This came about in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25394998/1). Is this a bug in javac? Or am I missing something dead obvious here?

Comment: This is a bug. You (or someone) should report it to Oracle.

Comment: Indeed, it's a bug in the Java 8 compiler, it reports the correct error with javac 7

Comment: Looks like it is already filed. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8033675. Good to know this bug.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't Java pass int\[\] to vararg?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394998/why-wont-java-pass-int-to-vararg)

Comment: the bug was closed as not an issue. Please check the comments at https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8033675

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug and has been reported as [JDK-8055514](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8055514). (By you?)

Comment: Probably @ajb, That bug report has javac 1.8.0_05

Comment: It's also a regression, `javac 1.7.0_51 output: Test.java:5: error: non-static method print(int...) cannot be referenced from a static context`, thanks for hunting down the bug reports... I knew about the ones at bugs.java.com but not here.