# Why does NetBeans warn about passing int[] to vararg?

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions, primitive-types, netbeans-8

**Why does the NetBeans precompiler give a warning for this?**

```
public class PrimitiveVarArgs
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] ints = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        prints(ints);
    }

    static void prints(int... ints)
    {
        for(int i : ints)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

It complains about line 5, saying:

```
Confusing primitive array passed to vararg method
```

but as far as I ([and others on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2426504/453435)) know, `int...` is the same as `int[]`. This works if it's a non-primitive type, like `String`, but not on primitives.

I can't even add this method:

```
void prints(int[] ints)
{
    for(int i : ints)
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

because the compiler says:

```
name clash: prints(int[]) and prints(int...) have the same erasure

cannot declare both prints(int[]) and prints(int...) in PrimitiveVarArgs
```

Upon looking into the NetBeans hints settings, I find it says this:

> A primitive array passed to variable-argument method will not be unwrapped and its items will not be seen as items of the variable-length argument in the called method. Instead, the array will be passed as a single item.

However, when I run the file (since it's just a warning and not an error), I get exactly the output I expect:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

so, **why doesn't NetBeans like me passing a native array to a varargs method?**

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Funny thing is, both of these questions are on the front page right now

Comment: The question does not deserve the downvotes. But you should rephrase the question so that it doesn't look exactly like the other.

Comment: @staticx The question isn't the same, though. OP just wants the answer, which is that this is a Netbeans bug, moved here.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: As it is phrased and laid out right now, it looks like an exact dupe.

Comment: Have you tried updating NetBeans?  [This link](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242627) seems to indicate that the problem has been fixed, although I can't tell whether the fix is available yet.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the upvote or downvote is a matter of what other users think if this question is useful (or not) for future readers, so I don't think there's a good/bad reason for voting this specific question. Apart of that, this bug can be easily searched on the net, no need to raise a question here...

Comment: OH MY GOSH GUYS you ask me to move it to a new question and then you mark it as a duplicate?!

Comment: Note: "guys" is probably incorrect, note only one user marked this question as a duplicate. I'd consider opening a meta discussion in your shoes.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza so an SO question is invalid because there's something on the Internet that answers it? Don't see any reference to such a concept in the rules.

Comment: @jdphenix doesn't it take a consensus of 5 to close a question?

Comment: @Supuhstar http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59693/room-for-jdphenix-and-supuhstar

Comment: @Supuhstar: People with gold badges in a tag can close questions with 1 vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bug in NetBeans.

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242627

Consider the following code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ints = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        prints(ints);
    }

    static void prints(Object... ints) {
        for(Object i : ints) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[I@15db9742 // on my machine
```

Versus this code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] ints = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        prints(ints);
    }

    static void prints(Object... ints) {
        for(Object i : ints) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Notice in my examples the signature of `prints()`. It accepts `Object...`, not `int...`. NetBeans is trying to warn you that something "strange" (unexpected) might happen, but erroneously reports that `prints(int...)` could do something "unexpected".

Comment: I'm using NetBeans 8.0. I note that bug is marked as `RESOLVED FIXED`, but do you know when that'll propagate to stable releases?

Comment: @Supuhstar No, but I'd just disable it for now (hover, click on `Configure confusing varargs...`, uncheck, go from there)

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 11.2, and I confirm the bug is still there.